# Added a c++ class to unreal engine , however failed to generate project files

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint, unreal-development-kit, unreal

When creating my unreal project, i selected blueprints. Now i want to export the transform details a character to an external file. I cannot find a way to do it through blueprints so i have to integrate c++. To do so i added a c++ class. But after adding i get an error that says

"Successfully added class"MyCharacter", however, you must recompile the "test" module before it will appear in the Content Browser. Failed to generate project files. Would you like to open the Output log to see more details"

When I close the project and open it again, it does not open and is asking me to fix source files manually

"The following modules are missing or built with a different engine version:
MyProject2
Would you like to rebuild them now?"

when I click yes further says:

"MyProject2 could not be compiled. Try rebuilding from source manually."

[Error shown when creating c++ class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os2iQ.png)

I was expecting for a class file to be open and i be able to edit character functions on Visual Studio.

Comment: What does the output log say? Also, is this a Blueprint only project?

Answer (score 2):

With the unreal editor closed, right click on your project's .uproject file (in the root directory of your project) and select "Generate Visual Studio project files".

If it succeeded you will now have a {ProjectName}.sln file in the root project directory. Opening it will open your project in visual studio and you can build from there and see what's going wrong.

If generating the project files failed, you should have log files inside /Saved/Logs that should tell you what's gone wrong.